# Checkboxes unchecked after cart.js end of update animation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to update a chart.js chart after the user has checked a checkbox.

I have a prototype here:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/henrikg112/pen/BaQaemK?editors=1111)

But the checkboxes are unchecking themselves when the animation has run to an end. It is somehow related to the update of the chart.js:

```
function recalc(sender) {
  chart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = Math.random() * 3000;
  chart.update(
    {
    duration: 1500,  
    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On change i recreate all the checkboxes, so obviously they will not remeber the state, since i change them all out.